# adaptIntegrate in r

Tags: r, numerical-integration

Does anyone know if `adaptIntegrate` accepts a vectorized integrand?

for e.g.

```
alpha<-c(1,2)

f <- function(z){
(z[1]+z[2])*alpha
}

adaptIntegrate(f,lower=c(1, 3), upper=c(2, 4),tol=0.01) ##does not work
```

Is what I want possible with `adaptIntegrate`?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself - add `fDim=2` among the arguments of adaptIntegrate. More generally,

```
fDim=length(alpha)
```